# how can sort alphabetically a text file?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to sort a text file

with text like that

word1,word2,word3
word1,word2,word3
word1,word2,word3
.

.

.

word5,word6,word3

I need to sort but this code is not working

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class myclass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string infile =  File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\finalregex.txt"); 
        string outfile = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\finalregex.txt"); 
        var contents = File.ReadAllLines(infile);
        Array.Sort(contents);
        File.WriteAllLines(outfile, contents);
    }
}
```

please help me

Comment: Sort by what? What do you want the end result to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the format in your example, this should suffice:

```
// File paths.
const string inFile = "in.txt";
const string outFile = "out.txt";

// Read file.
var inContents = File.ReadAllText(inFile);

// Organize contents.
var contentsArray = inContents.Replace(Environment.NewLine, ",")
    .Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// Sort contents.
var sortedContents = contentsArray.OrderBy(c => c);

// Write file.
File.WriteAllText(outFile, string.Join(",", sortedContents));
```